# JQuery - draggable DIV to fade between images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6NTSV/) about my problem.

I want to drag the slider (with speech bubble above it) left and right. As it slides between the blue and green colours on the bar behind it, it will set the opacity of `image 1 to 90%` and the opacity of `image 2 to 10%`, `image1 80% image 2 20%, image 1 70% - image2 30%` etc till the slider reaches end of green and the `opacity` of `image 1 is set to 0% and image 2 to 100%`, then as the slider keeps sliding to the right, `from green to red`, `image 2 reaches 0% and image 3 is 100%`. Repeat with the next image.

I've looked at http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/ which seems to do what I want, but I'm not sure how to get the X position of the slider, then apply that to the opacity of image1, image2, image3, image4.

The slider is `960px wide`, so `960 / 4 = 240`, for each `240 pixels` along the slider the opacity needs to be set from 0-100%.

Firstly, is this possible in jquery? Secondly, can anyone help with the code or show me some links which may help?

Comment: I can't see the images in the example :/

Comment: Yes i have used the same slider. I can give you useful hint!

Comment: The images are on top of eachother @Antimated arranged by Z-INDEX :) So if I set the opacity of the top image to 50%, 50% of the image below would show through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({

        range: "min",
                 value: 0,
                 min: 0,
                 max: 10,

                 slide: function (event, ui) {
                     var r = (ui.value); 
                     $("#img1").css({'opacity':r/10});
                     $("#img2").css({'opacity':1-(r/10)});
}   
    })
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img id = "img1" src = "http://www.gettyimages.com/images/marketing/frontdoorStill/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:200px">
<img id = "img2" src = "http://www.gettyimages.com/images/marketing/frontdoorStill/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg" style = "height:200px; width:200px">
<div id="slider" style = "height:10px; width:400px" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi MJQ, thanks for this example, this would only work for 2 images though. I'm not sure how to extend this for 4 images?

Comment: It can be extended. Just make a logic and add it while changing the attributes. That's upto you!

Comment: Hi MJQ, I'm quite new to javascript/jquery. Can you tell me what "Make a logic" means???

Comment: You have to set the opacity according to the number of images you want to add. Just understand the code I shared and then enhance it. It is too simple!

Comment: Hi MJQ. Your code does not work. I've tried putting it in jsfiddle and it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the code with a working solution and with images. Make an html file and paste it there! Enjoy!